# Merging two lines into one within a file for a specific pattern

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I am a novice in shell scripting . I have a input like this

```
abc
 xyz
cdf
kjd
mno
abc
 xyzjhd
lkds
kmdew
abc
  yzxnh
```

I need a output which is in form

```
abcxyz
cdf
kjd
mno
abcxyzjhd
lkds
kmdew
abcyzxnh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This awk makes it:

```
$ awk '/^ / {gsub(/^[ ]*/, ""); print a$0; a=""; next} {if (a) print a; a=$0}' file
abcxyz
cdf
kjd
mno
abcxyzjhd
lkds
kmdew
abcyzxnh
```

#### Explanation

- `/^ / {}` on lines starting with space, do `{}`.
- `{gsub(/^[ ]*/, ""); print a$0; a=""; next}` remove all of leading spaces and print the previous line together with current one. Then jump to next line.
- `{if (a) print a; a=$0}` otherwise, and if `a` is set, print the previous line. Also, store the current one in the `a` variable.

Answer (score 2):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line*, for all other text manipulation the standard UNIX tool is awk. This problem involves doing things across multiple lines (specifically joining 2 lines) and therefore sed should not be considered for a solution and therefore you need an awk solution.

This uses GNU awk to read all lines from the file into a single string and then delete all occurrences of a newline followed by blank chars from that string:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{gsub(/\n[[:blank:]]+/,"")}1' file
abcxyz
cdf
kjd
mno
abcxyzjhd
lkds
kmdew
abcyzxnh
```

Note that the above uses the [:blank:] character class which does not include newlines so ALL it will do is append a line that starts with blank chars to the preceding line.

* sed has language constructs for doing things across multiple lines but those constructs became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented. The only sed language constructs that are still appropriate to use are s, g, and p (with -n). If you need anything else from sed then you are using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 1):

gawk:

```
kent$  awk -v RS="" '{gsub(/\n\s+/,"")}7' file   
abcxyz
cdf
kjd
mno
abcxyzjhd
lkds
kmdew
abcyzxnh
```

Comment: This will also remove empty lines and if there are no empty lines then likely the maximum record length may be exceeded with larger files..

Comment: @Scrutinizer OP didn't give those requirement, this line works for OP's example, if OP has further requirement, I will update the answer. but thanks for your points.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed 'N;/\n .*/{s/\n//; s/ \+//;};P;D' yourfile
```

**OR**

```
sed 'N;/\n .*/{s/\n \+//;};P;D' yourfile
```

If want in-place edit,

```
sed -i.bak 'N;/\n .*/{s/\n \+//;};P;D' yourfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`

```
awk 'NR>1{ORS=sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/,x)?x:RS; print p} {p=$0} END{ORS=RS; print p}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;s/\n  *//;P;D' file
```

Read the next line and remove the previous newline and any following spaces if there are spaces at the beginning of a line.

If there are likely to be more than one such line, then:

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/\n  *//;ta;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;${x;s/\n //g;p}' YourFile
```

same idea as @sat but with the whole file in memory and change once using `g`

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n\s+//g' file
```

or if the lines to be joined always starts with `abc`:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(abc)\s*\n\s+/$1/g' file
```